# Polymer: How to pass sub-object as binding to the custom element

Tags: polymer, polymer-starter-kit

Suppose I have created a custom element as follow:

```
<chat-container messages="{{ messages }}"></chat-container>
```

`messages` is an array containing chat messages related to any particular thread or contact.

Now, in my `app.js`, I have this kind of message array which contains all messages by thread identifiers. How can I pass the messages related to any particular thread identifier(i.e name='Rajat') to `<chat-container>` element? I have tried nearly all combinations and still nothing is making sense.

```
 app.messages =  [
     {name: 'Rajat', messages: [{id: 1,message: 'Hello'},{id: 3,message: 'Hello 2'}]},
     {name: 'Himesh', messages: [{id: 2,message: 'Hello'}]},
     {name: 'David', messages: [{id: 4,message: 'Hello'}]}
    ]
```

I tried to do:

```
<chat-container messages="{{ app.messages.filter(function(e) { return e.name === 'Rajat'; })[0].messages }}"></chat-container>
```

and it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Polymer doesn't support such complex binding expression. Move the filter code to a function and call that function from the binding expression.  Binding expressions only support ``` .``! ```, `()`

```
<chat-container messages="{{filter('name', 'Rajat')}}"></chat-container>
```

where the parent element has a function named `filter()`

Comment: I am using Polymer 1.0? Is this the correct syntax?

Comment: Sorry, forgot an `{`